# badges / achievements

Tags: c#, sql-server

i'm looking to implement a similar thing to stackoverflow badges. you could also equate them to achievements in games.

but am not sure **how to design the database/code/tracking for them**.

i get what i should do for badges such as:

> Altruist × 1456  First bounty you manually awarded on another person's question

because they are a one time event, but how to handle others such as:

> Analytical × 16389  Visited every section of the FAQ
>    Electorate × 1783  Voted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions
>    Outspoken × 188  Posted 10 messages in chat that were starred by 10 different users

etc...

how to handle them, how to keep track of progress for each, etc... is there a tutorial or something that can help me figure out a design pattern for them?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For the given examples, there are essentially two mechanisms you are going to need.

I don't know how it's done on SO, this is just a suggestion of a solution.

Let's look at 'Analytical' first. You are going to have to record by means of a simple flag when a user visits a particular area in the FAQ. Let's envisage a DB table with a field for each FAQ section and a user ID. This starts off as "N" (or 0, or however you want to represent your flag). When a user visits that area, you call code to flip that field to "Y". When all fields are "Y" then you can award that badge.

As for 'electorate' and 'Outspoken', you can retrieve this information by means of a query on your existing data, assuming the queries themseves are not too burdensome. You are going to need to consider when to run these checks. This essentially boils down to two options.

1) When the an action is performed that might get a badge awarded (i.e. visit section of FAQ, Vote on a Question, Question starred by someone else)

2) Periodically (hourly, daily, etc) run a check for all your badges against current data.

Bear in mind that badges are one-way in Stackoverflow, so if you are wanting to be equivalent then you don't have to consider logic to 'un-award' badges.

Comment: i think i get it now. seems easy :P just one issue - you say for 'analytical' to use a db table, but there will be many such similar badges and how would i go about for each of them? i should use a different table for each badge, or is there some way of unifying this into a single table? otherwise i might end up with a lot of db tables, one for each badge type... but thnx for the answer - it helps a lot to get me started in the right direction. btw, your 2 means that badges do not get awarded at the very moment they are achieved, right? and yes, there won't be un-awarding.

Comment: How you implement the table is up to you. You could have a 4 column table with user_id, badge_id, badge_acheivement_id, flag - This would make it scalable to multiple badges. And, yes it means that they woudln't be awarded the very moment they were achieved.

Comment: of course :) thank you. i think this solves all my issues. i guess scheduling checks quite often is a possibility to lower the gap of time between 'earning' the badge and the badge being shown.

Comment: You'll need to consider the costs of running the checks for 'all badges for all users every set period' versus 'for one badge for one user every time they might meet the criteria.' It'll depend on the number of badges, number of users, frequency of user interactions etc. Lots of badges/users would favour option 1, lots of interactions would favour option 2.